# sf::st_intersection not implement all points

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I have two sf files: x & Riv

I would like to obtain the intersection of 'x' polylines with 'Riv' Linestring. For that, I used the function `sf::st_intersection(x,Riv)`.
Nevertheless, the output does not include all the intersection with all 'x' linestrings.
(Only 27 on 44)

The sf file 'x' come from the application of the `st_nearest_points()`between Riv and a former sf file (in green in the figure on below). Then all 'x' lines should have an intersection with 'Riv'.

I would like to find a way to include all the missing x lines in the outputs (in red in the on figure) and not only the few selected (in blue on the figure).

```
x <- structure(list(structure(c(163340.962516503, 163339.007569445, 
86055.2969082572, 86057.5225402927), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163344.400724905, 163343.429912257, 
86058.3169561776, 86059.4221890382), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163343.975166494, 163343.159782333, 
86057.9431548709, 86058.8714383775), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163340.371658435, 163338.188246187, 
86054.7779113055, 86057.2636421723), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163358.985477678, 163358.405840557, 
86057.1043793742, 86056.243204223), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163337.034088493, 163336.815430932, 
86052.5278108928, 86052.9286830882), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163343.251330057, 163341.479437086, 
86057.3073525952, 86059.3245845931), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163340.38060113, 163339.576337948, 
86054.785766375, 86055.7013890743), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163342.6099935, 163341.283701168, 
86056.7440164302, 86058.2539492389), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163336.398516082, 163335.875658191, 
86052.1811350321, 86053.1397078326), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163359.765722677, 163357.848655319, 
86056.5823423227, 86053.7067412864), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163341.887132772, 163341.429950661, 
86056.109071196, 86056.6295554452), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163341.612846091, 163341.473399649, 
86055.8681437061, 86056.0268981168), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163337.333727026, 163336.984452273, 
86052.6912500924, 86053.3315871395), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163347.378671305, 163347.203945911, 
86060.0021536016, 86060.4972088849), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163330.103100902, 163330.035532865, 
86049.5971912096, 86050.0279374449), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163351.681033356, 163351.828097384, 
86060.6313092021, 86061.3265209692), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163358.810584269, 163359.400106365, 
86057.2220960919, 86058.0979574919), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163320.051020384, 163319.91809282, 
86049.0132598105, 86048.122645136), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163322.057491585, 163321.958762763, 
86048.7137864969, 86048.0523033906), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.663260317, 163321.531477757, 
86048.7726269846, 86047.8896838333), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.720228212, 163321.388596349, 
86048.7641243137, 86046.5421908274), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.179157688, 163321.200699036, 
86048.8448811083, 86048.9892081348), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163355.863493616, 163354.256530111, 
86059.2057148, 86056.8182261633), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.776604765, 163321.528371423, 
86048.7557099029, 86047.0925465152), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163320.763208813, 163320.771370347, 
86048.90696303, 86048.9616453042), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163358.156758331, 163357.230257917, 
86057.662171242, 86056.2856563414), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163329.134219573, 163328.981016192, 
86049.4452098247, 86050.4218813749), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.814856331, 163321.834515089, 
86048.7500007138, 86048.8817143925), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163320.297973082, 163320.356287921, 
86048.9764011989, 86049.3671106212), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.747157576, 163321.715059441, 
86048.7601050058, 86048.545047503), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163356.166413244, 163354.726073394, 
86059.001826589, 86056.8618930979), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163363.182741817, 163363.228177877, 
86054.4241853348, 86055.0754355295), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163514.131668895, 163514.116761467, 
86092.5347591268, 86092.984963432), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163536.571089144, 163536.637359745, 
86093.7360065682, 86092.5002547856), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163423.973839794, 163424.105831473, 
86059.3596477238, 86058.9129066588), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163632.368401207, 163632.39098375, 
86190.762703538, 86190.4820347959), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163444.094941805, 163443.50918856, 
86060.4176706545, 86062.4491127571), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163360.049154527, 163359.108284222, 
86056.3933877558, 86054.982082298), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163356.474576667, 163355.752668853, 
86058.7944089005, 86057.721860148), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163362.583680115, 163361.324256662, 
86054.7037040303, 86052.8145688502), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163413.172675529, 163413.167783795, 
86057.2378796361, 86058.0401240094), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163320.98844555, 163320.710672094, 
86048.8733456066, 86047.0122634526), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.10674043, 163320.715609176, 
86048.8556896544, 86046.2351102559), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, precision = 0, crs = structure(list(
    input = "BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"BD72\",\n        DATUM[\"Reseau National Belge 1972\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"International 1924\",6378388,297,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4313]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Belgian Lambert 72\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",90,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",4.36748666666667,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",51.1666672333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",49.8333339,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",150000.013,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",5400088.438,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Belgium - onshore.\"],\n        BBOX[49.5,2.5,51.51,6.4]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",31370]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
"sfc"), bbox = structure(c(xmin = 163319.91809282, ymin = 86046.2351102559, 
xmax = 163632.39098375, ymax = 86190.762703538), class = "bbox"))
```

```
Riv <- Riv <- structure(list(id = 1, Type = NA_character_, geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(163293.837499969, 163298.070833307, 163303.18611109, 
    163310.77083332, 163317.38541666, 163323.294444444, 163332.290277786, 
    163339.081250015, 163345.607638911, 163350.105555582, 163354.691666698, 
    163359.277777814, 163362.981944484, 163366.774305599, 163371.007638937, 
    163373.477083384, 163416.868750095, 163424.629861214, 163427.716666772, 
    163443.238889011, 163457.61458347, 163468.021527925, 163473.136805708, 
    163479.839583492, 163489.71736128, 163500.918055736, 163514.235416861, 
    163542.193055778, 163550.659722453, 163557.450694683, 163561.772222465, 
    163570.503472474, 163574.031250255, 163573.590278032, 163570.679861363, 
    163566.181944692, 163560.802083575, 163561.419444687, 163563.359722466, 
    163568.29861136, 163569.533333584, 163573.325694699, 163575.706944701, 
    163583.820833598, 163593.610416942, 163595.9034725, 163599.960416948, 
    163605.957639177, 163622.802778083, 163638.148611432, 163646.174305884, 
    163659.668055898, 163670.251389242, 163690.536111485, 86050.9986111142, 
    86054.438194451, 86056.4666666753, 86053.4680555611, 86049.4111111126, 
    86048.5291666672, 86049.9402777798, 86053.6444444502, 86059.377083345, 
    86060.9645833466, 86059.9944444567, 86056.907638898, 86054.438194451, 
    86054.1736111174, 86055.761111119, 86056.9958333425, 86057.2604166761, 
    86059.553472234, 86060.6118055684, 86060.1708333457, 86064.3159722389, 
    86071.4597222462, 86078.1625000308, 86087.2465278178, 86090.6861111547, 
    86092.0972222672, 86092.5381944899, 86094.037500047, 86097.2125000502, 
    86099.5937500526, 86104.444444502, 86116.8798611814, 86127.375000081, 
    86133.9013889765, 86141.3979167619, 86146.7777778785, 86151.7166667725, 
    86155.9500001101, 86165.3868056753, 86181.7909723587, 86187.7000001425, 
    86196.8722223741, 86201.2819446008, 86203.8395834923, 86203.8395834923, 
    86200.4000001555, 86195.372916817, 86192.5506945919, 86189.9930557004, 
    86191.2277779239, 86193.4326390372, 86194.1381945935, 86193.7854168154, 
    86186.5534723636), dim = c(54L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(input = "BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"BD72\",\n        DATUM[\"Reseau National Belge 1972\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"International 1924\",6378388,297,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4313]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Belgian Lambert 72\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",90,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",4.36748666666667,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",51.1666672333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",49.8333339,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",150000.013,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",5400088.438,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Belgium - onshore.\"],\n        BBOX[49.5,2.5,51.51,6.4]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",31370]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 163293.837499969, 
ymin = 86048.5291666672, xmax = 163690.536111485, ymax = 86203.8395834923
), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(id = NA_integer_, 
Type = NA_integer_), class = "factor", levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

[image: Representation of the problematic]

**EDIT:** The original sf object, used for `st_nearest_point()`

```
ori <- structure(list(N = c(1, 2, 3, 10, 12, 20, 23, 25, 26, 30, 34, 
46, 51, 61, 62, 68, 69, 83, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 14, 17, 19, 21, 24, 
25, 26, 30, 32, 36, 37, 40, 44, 55, 57, 58, 59, 74, 3, 31, 32
), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(163339.007569445, 86057.5225402927
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163343.429912257, 
86059.4221890382), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163343.159782333, 
86058.8714383775), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163338.188246187, 
86057.2636421723), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163358.405840557, 
86056.243204223), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163336.815430932, 
86052.9286830882), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163341.479437086, 
86059.3245845931), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163339.576337948, 
86055.7013890743), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163341.283701168, 
86058.2539492389), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163335.875658191, 
86053.1397078326), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163357.848655319, 
86053.7067412864), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163341.429950661, 
86056.6295554452), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163341.473399649, 
86056.0268981168), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163336.984452273, 
86053.3315871395), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163347.203945911, 
86060.4972088849), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163330.035532865, 
86050.0279374449), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163351.828097384, 
86061.3265209692), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163359.400106365, 
86058.0979574919), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163319.91809282, 
86048.122645136), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.958762763, 
86048.0523033906), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.531477757, 
86047.8896838333), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.388596349, 
86046.5421908274), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.200699036, 
86048.9892081348), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163354.256530111, 
86056.8182261633), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.528371423, 
86047.0925465152), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163320.771370347, 
86048.9616453042), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163357.230257917, 
86056.2856563414), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163328.981016192, 
86050.4218813749), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.834515089, 
86048.8817143925), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163320.356287921, 
86049.3671106212), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163321.715059441, 
86048.545047503), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163354.726073394, 
86056.8618930979), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163363.228177877, 
86055.0754355295), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163514.116761467, 
86092.984963432), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163536.637359745, 
86092.5002547856), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163424.105831473, 
86058.9129066588), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163632.39098375, 
86190.4820347959), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163443.50918856, 
86062.4491127571), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163359.108284222, 
86054.982082298), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163355.752668853, 
86057.721860148), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163361.324256662, 
86052.8145688502), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163413.167783795, 
86058.0401240094), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163320.710672094, 
86047.0122634526), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163320.715609176, 
86046.2351102559), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 163319.91809282, 
ymin = 86046.2351102559, xmax = 163632.39098375, ymax = 86190.4820347959
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:31370", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"BD72\",\n        DATUM[\"Reseau National Belge 1972\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"International 1924\",6378388,297,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4313]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Belgian Lambert 72\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",90,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",4.36748666666667,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",51.1666672333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",49.8333339,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",150000.013,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",5400088.438,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Belgium - onshore.\"],\n        BBOX[49.5,2.5,51.51,6.4]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",31370]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
44L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(N = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Comment: sf doesn't seem to like those objects and spits out `Error in CPL_crs_parameters(x) : OGR error` on both `Riv` and `x`

Comment: I have updated the code now. I don't know why, it has to be inserted in a markdown file first... If not, it doesn't seems to work

Comment: Better, no issues with `x` anymore, but I'm afraid both objects in question are now the same - `Riv` is also series of 2-point linestrings, identical to those in `x`. Could you also share original points, those used in `st_nearest_points()`?

Comment: I have changed `Riv` and had the original sf object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are missing intersections, so those failing `x` lines are still slightly off, with gap distances in ~ 1e-10 range. Precision and floating point representation can hit hard ... experimenting with [precision](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html#precision) and rounding could work, but let's test [sfnetworks](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/). And let's use points from `ori`, the original sf object.

Note that this will alter geometries -- `Riv` is split at each blend / intersection point and later unioned back together, resulting shape will not be identical to the original. And I can't even guess if/how it scales performance-wise.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(sfnetworks)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(dplyr)

# check distances between x and Riv, meters
# everything > 0 will not intersect
st_distance(x,Riv) |> c()
#> Units: [m]
#>  [1] 5.127934e-11 0.000000e+00 1.560592e-10 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
#> ...
#> [41] 5.415751e-11 3.582375e-11 1.468602e-11 0.000000e+00

# sfnetworks provides convenient st_network_blend()
net <- as_sfnetwork(Riv) |> 
  st_network_blend(ori)
autoplot(net) + theme_bw()

# extract nodes (blend points) from network,
# filter out Riv endpoints 
n_points <- net |> 
  activate(nodes) |> 
  filter(!is.na(N)) |> 
  st_as_sf()

# extract edges (segmented Riv, lines) from network,
# union to multiline
n_riv <- net |> 
  activate(edges) |> 
  st_as_sf() |>
  st_union()

# check distance
st_distance(n_points, n_riv) |> c()
#> Units: [m]
#>  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> [39] 0 0 0 0 0 0

# check intersecting points
st_intersects(n_points, n_riv) |> t() |> unlist()
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
#> [26] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = n_riv, alpha = .5) +
  geom_sf(data = n_points, aes(color = "n_points"), shape = 4) +
  geom_sf(data = ori, aes(color = "ori"), shape = 4) +
  geom_sf(data = x, aes(color = "x")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_bw()
```

`autoplot(net)`:
[image]

Resulting geometries along with `x` lines for reference:
[image]
[image]
[image]